# What would be a typical usecase to use a lambda expression in Bash?

Tags: bash, function

This is not a "problem to solve" question but rather a question about Bash didactics, literature and what's common between teachers.

What would be a typical usecase to use an anonymous/unnamed procedure ("lambda expression") in Bash?

Comment: sounds like a homework question

Comment: maybe I'm just silly, but even though I do a lot of bash programming, I think it is not a great programming language, and if you are doing lambda's in bash, perhaps you are using the wrong language.

Comment: @Bravo it's unlikely that this an homework question as I seek a random answer but anyway I suggest you to believe me that this is not an homework question...

Comment: forgive my assumption, functional**student** - your use of the word **teachers** and **didactics** coupled with your username suggests a student->teacher relationship. The answer you seek is not random at all, as a typical usecase is never random, instead a "typical usecase of x" would answer the question "what is a typical usecase of x"

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous functions are available in `zsh`, where they provide a way of writing a section of a script with local variables. You can't however pass them as arguments to other functions, but as you can pass an arbitrary string to functions, you could pass the *name* of any function and then call that (you could do that in `bash` today if you wish).

Anonymous functions in `zsh` look like this:

```bsh
() {
    local myvar

    # Some code using $myvar as a temporary variable,
    # setting up things and possibly assigning to global variables.

} argument list here

# myvar from the function no longer exists here
```

The function is called when it's defined.

I use this in my `.zprofile` file to set up my `PATH` variable and for handling the setup of `ssh-agent` at the remote end of SSH connections (both of these things require a few local variables that I don't want hanging around).

The `zsh` manual contains this example code:

```bsh
variable=outside
function {
  local variable=inside
  print "I am $variable with arguments $*"
} this and that
print "I am $variable"
```

.... with the output

```
I am inside with arguments this and that
I am outside
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a lambda expression though

Comment: @roaima No, but anonymous functions, also mentioned in the question.